# rabbitmq client loses connectivity

Tags: java, scala, rabbitmq

Here's a scala code in play framework to publish messages. All goes well until I restart play server. When I restart play server, client exits immediately.

```
val connection = RabbitMQConnection.getConnection(uri)
val channel = connection.createChannel()
channel.queueDeclare( QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null)

channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME,true,
      MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN,
      cmdLine.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there a fix?
Below is the client code:

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setUri(rabbitmq_uri);
    factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(30);
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
    channel.basicQos(1);

    Consumer consumer = getConsumer(channel);

    boolean autoAck = false;
    channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, autoAck, consumer);
```

Comment: What error message do you see in the RabbitMQ log ?

Comment: client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

Comment: Which version of RabbitMQ and Erlang are you using ?
Try with anincreased connection timeout. Also, check your firewall configuration.

Comment: erlang:system_info(otp_release). "19"

Comment: rabbitmq-server-3.6.14-1.el7.noarch.rpm

Comment: Increased timeout to 60 sec. yet to test

Comment: Exited again after ~8+ hrs

Comment: "shutdownCompleted" did not get called.

Comment: Ironically, all 3 listeners on 3 different machines exit at the same time

Comment: I am testing out slurm independent of rabbitmq ... could this cause client to unexpectedly close connection?

Comment: Could be.... You could also try to use a more recent version or RMQ and see if you still encounter the issue

Comment: upgraded to erlang 20 and rabbitmq 3.7.2 /// will see how it goes

Comment: srun -N3 -n6 hostname --> this is the command causing client to exit. but why? the rabbitmq server and client have nothing to do with srun

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'srun'. Can you try without it ?

Comment: srun is not used at all. I'm testing slurm for a different purpose.